# How do you add a connecting line to a google slides presentation using app scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to follow the Google Slides API reference material; ['Lines'](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/lines#Page.LineProperties) 
but I must be missing something. I have successfully added rectangle shapes using the script, but now I want to connect them with a line. Here is what I have so far:

```
function addConnections()
{
  var myPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  var presentationId = myPresentation.getId();
  var slideId = myPresentation.getSlides()[0].getObjectId()

  var requests = []

    requests.push(
    {
      createLine: 
      {
        lineProperties: 
        {
          startConnection: 
          {
            connectedObjectId: 'queryD200',
            connectionSiteIndex: 3
          },
          endConnection: 
          {
            connectedObjectId: 'queryD201',
            connectionSiteIndex: 0
          }
        },
        lineType: 'CURVED_CONNECTOR_2'
      }
    })

  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, presentationId);

}
```

The error that I get is:
Unknown name "lineType" at 'requests[0].create_line': Cannot find field.
Unknown name "lineProperties" at 'requests[0].create_line': Cannot find field.

But those are the exact field names that google uses in their documentation.
I tried them both with quotations and without. Please Help! and thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to connect 2 shapes with a line on Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Slides API with Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- There is no property of `lineProperties` in `createLine`.
- There is no property of `lineType` in `LineProperties`.
- In your request body, the property of `fields` is not used.
- In order to connect 2 shapes with a line, in your situation, how about the following flow?

  1. Create a line object using `createLine`.
  2. Update the line object using `lineProperties`.

     - `lineProperties` can be used for the existing line object using `UpdateLinePropertiesRequest`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function addConnections() {
  var myPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  var presentationId = myPresentation.getId();
  var slideId = myPresentation.getSlides()[0].getObjectId();

  var lineObjectId = "sampleline001";
  var startShape = "queryD200";
  var endShape = "queryD201";

  var requests = [
    {createLine: {
      objectId: lineObjectId,
      lineCategory: "CURVED",
      elementProperties: {pageObjectId: slideId, size: {height: {magnitude: 1 ,unit: "PT"}, width: {magnitude: 1, unit: "PT"}}}
    }},
    {updateLineProperties: {
      objectId: lineObjectId,
      lineProperties: {startConnection: {connectedObjectId: startShape}, endConnection: {connectedObjectId: endShape}},
      fields: "startConnection,endConnection"
    }}
  ];
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, presentationId);
}
```

#### Sample script:

As another pattern, you can also achieve this using [Slides service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides) instead of Slides API.

```
function addConnections() {
  var myPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  var presentationId = myPresentation.getId();
  var slide = myPresentation.getSlides()[0];
  var slideId = slide.getObjectId();

  var startShape = "queryD200";
  var endShape = "queryD201";

  var line = slide.insertLine(
    SlidesApp.LineCategory.CURVED,
    slide.getPageElementById(startShape).asShape().getConnectionSites()[0],
    slide.getPageElementById(endShape).asShape().getConnectionSites()[0]
  );
}
```

#### Result:

When above both scripts are run for 2 shapes, the following result can be obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether the shape object IDs `queryD200` and `queryD201` are correct. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [CreateLineRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createlinerequest)
- [UpdateLinePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatelinepropertiesrequest)
- [insertLine(lineCategory, startConnectionSite, endConnectionSite)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertlinelinecategory,-startconnectionsite,-endconnectionsite)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and thorough response. I will look into your suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Comment: as for the shape object IDs I made them up, so I know they are correct.

Comment: @Day4 Thank you for replying. I added one more sample script without using Slides API. You can both scripts. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: That worked great, my problem was not understanding that I needed to create the line first and then modify it with "updateLineProperties" in a separate request. I like how slick your second suggestion is, however I opted to use the first because I had more than 400 lines to draw. So I created a loop to push the line create and line update objects to the request array. then threw it all through the batch update... cha-ching worked like a charm. Thanks Again

Comment: @Day4 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

@Tanaike
I am posing the code that I ended up using just in case it is useful to anyone else.
'arrayCon' is an array of elementId pairs that I needed to connect with the lines. There were well over 400 pairs but batching them together into one request array was very efficient taking no more than 3 or 4 seconds to complete.

```
for(var i = 0;i<arrayCon.length;i++)
  {
    var lineId = 'lineConn'+i;
    var startCon = arrayCon[i][0]
    var endCon = arrayCon[i][1]

    requests.push(
    {
      createLine: 
      {
        objectId: lineId,
        lineCategory: 'CURVED',
        elementProperties: {pageObjectId: slideId, size: {height: {magnitude: 1 ,unit: "PT"}, width: {magnitude: 1, unit: "PT"}}}
      }
    })
    requests.push(
    {
      updateLineProperties: 
      {
        objectId: lineId,
        fields: 'startConnection,endConnection',
        lineProperties: 
        {
          startConnection:
          {
            connectedObjectId: startCon,
            connectionSiteIndex: 2
          },
          endConnection:
          {
            connectedObjectId: endCon,
            connectionSiteIndex: 0
          }
        }
      }
    })

  }

  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, presentationId);

}
```